# Is it safe and efficient to install HHVM on top Apache server with nginx as reversed proxy?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx, performance, php

I've been trying to optimize my VPS for WordPress performance, and today, I decided to take it to a new level: I'm thinking about installing [HHVM](http://hhvm.com/).

**Server status**: My server runs Apache, and I have already installed and activated PHP-APC for caching and performance. Moreover, I installed nginx as a reversed proxy server for Apache by using 
[NginxCP](http://www.nginxcp.com/), which makes me a little worry because instead of one, I have 2 servers (Apache and nginx) running at the same time; and it surely takes some resources (My VPS has 6GB RAM), but magically, it does reduce the load time.

**Question & concern**: From the point of server performance, is it safe and efficient to install HHVM on top of those already-installed softwares on my server? I imagine it to be 3 big processes running and the same time, and I don't know if it does slow down the server somehow, because as I understand, HHVM will have to re-compile the code one more time after it has gone through nginx and Apache.

P/S: I'm not too familiar with server administration and on the learning curve, please do help me by correcting anything I am wrong. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why are you keeping Apache?

Comment: Because I'm not quite sure if removing it will affect WordPress at all. Plus, I'm using cPanel so I think it's better to keep it for support. If I remove it, will I need to reconfigure anything to make all the current site work?

Comment: hhvm replaces mod_php/php-fpm - the rest of the stack is irrelevant to evaluating the use of hhvm (using apache _and_ nginx, on the server is not likely to be optimal). The best advice you'll receive is: **test it and see if it works** - you're currently comparing a known to an unknown and asking odd questions whilst only thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

nginx is able to talk with any backend listening on a FastCGI socket. That includes PHP-FPM and HHVM, provided both frontend and backend are configured to find each other.

Thus, it not efficiant to use 3 layers `nginx <-> Apache <-> PHP backend` while you could only have 2 layers `nginx/Apache <-> PHP backend`. You would need to decide which Web server you would prefer to use.

I do not understand what might be unsafe, though, provided you use a setup suitable to be a server, up-to-date and properly configured. Security covers a wide range of different scopes, starting from network design, passing through OS configuration, up to individual Web server locations configuration.

Provided you use stable software and an easy/automated method for maintenance/updates, I do not see why it would not be suitable for production.

Anyway, the baseline is: you only install the bare minimum of stuff you need on a server. Security is helped by simplicity/cleanliness.